# Equivalent to Matlab's ind2rgb in Python

Tags: python, image, matlab

In Matlab, there is a function `ind2rgb` function that can be used like this:

```matlab
y = ind2rgb(im2uint8(rescale(cfs)),jet(256));
```

From the [Matlab website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html):

> `RGB = ind2rgb(X,map)` converts the indexed image `X` and corresponding colormap `map` to RGB (truecolor) format.

Is there an equivalent method in Python?

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: @mkrieger1.  I added the verbiage for the `ind2rgb` Matlab command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about an inbuilt equivalent but you can easily do this using `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# Create a 5x5 array of indices for demo
img = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5)) 

# Create a fake grayscale colormap for demo
cmap = np.vstack((np.linspace(0, 1, n), np.linspace(0, 1, n), np.linspace(0, 1, n))).T
```

Now, the `i`th row of `cmap` gives you the color, and every element of `img` tells you which index in `cmap` is the color for that pixel so you just need to take the `i`th row for each element `i` in `img`. Because numpy's indexing works with broadcasting, you can give the entire `img` array as the row indexer, and you'll get an array of shape `(img_rows, img_cols, cmap_cols)`

```
rgb_img = cmap[img, :]
print(rgb_img.shape) # (5, 5, 3)
```

In other words, `ind2rgb(img, cmap)` is equivalent to `cmap[img, :]`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your solution.  I have my `img` array which is (286,500).  I'm still not sure how to get from `img` in your code to the `rgb_img`?  Do I generate a `cmap` with n=500?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe `cmap` is a 256x3 array (same as in Matlab) if you want a 256-color image